# How can i preserve squid ink

Tags: food-preservation, seafood

I clean my own squids and I want to preserve the ink for later use.
I was wondering what to do with the ink sac. Should I collect the ink in a little jar and freeze it?

Or how long will it last in the refrigerator?

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you do with the ink later? Can you cook with it?

Comment: @Rikon: Squid Ink can be used to prepare a black rice recipe, among other things.
Sinan: yes, you can freeze the squid ink. Just put it on a small ziploc bag and you're done.

Comment: @Rikon as mines said. I was thinking about making some black pasta.

Comment: I always figure that anything that's already completely liquid will do very well freezing; there's no structure to destroy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand you should be able to extract the ink and freeze it for later use. Users on [this forum](http://forum.downsizer.net/viewtopic.php?t=26672&start=0) suggest extracting the ink and then freezing. Another person [here](http://forums.egullet.org/index.php?/topic/112537-looking-for-squid-ink-in-seattle/) says:

> I save my ink from freshly cleaned squid and just freeze it

So it looks like your best bet would be to extract the ink from the sacs into a suitable freezer container and freeze it.

Freezing will definitely help it to last longer as the [shelf life of squid in the refrigerator is 1-2 days. You can extend this to 3-5 months in the freezer](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18401). I'd imagine the squid ink would have a similar shelf life.